# How to execute code after ALL AJAX loaded elements and code have fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a widget that dynamically loads bits and pieces of HTML & JS code & files on-demand as the user interacts with the widget.

I am running into a problem with some code/files not loading fully before the next piece of code that depends on it executes.  This causes missing buttons in jQuery dialogs and HTML code blocks that never get shown because the JS that shows them executes before its ready.

I've tried both of the following jQuery methods but neither works consistently:

```
$("#dynamic1, script[name$='/forms.js']").ready(function () {/* my code*/});
$("#dynamic1, script[name$='/forms.js']").load(function () {/* my code*/});
```

I need to make sure that ALL items the code is dependent on are loaded the "my code" block is execute and it needs to be executed only once.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: already tried with a loader like RequireJS? maybe you need to combine that with Deferreds and `$.when`. Let me know if I'm on the right path and I can write up something to guide you on that direction.

Comment: Can you show the code for the AJAX calls and their callbacks?

Comment: I haven't tried RequireJS but I'm now looking at it as an option. I tried changing some of the AJAX calls to async:false, but that is still creating instances (far less tho) of code just not loading in time. For instance, if I create a dialog like `$("selector").dialog({buttons: {Submit: submitResultFunc, Cancel: function () {$e(this).dialog('close');}})` with that callback to submitResultFunc and that function is declared in forms.js, then I need to make sure that script is fully loaded and all functions are available.  If they aren't, then the "Submit" button just doesn't show.

Comment: So I tried using $.when as gonchuki suggested and wrapped all my getScript calls in it. Oddly, when I did that, cross domain requests for scripts don't fire at all anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.when(

  // one or multiple ajax requests 

).then(function() {

  // After the ajax request is done

});
```